# Is it correct to use: 'to cooperate in a group/team' as a synonym for 'to work in a team'?

Tags: phrases

If it is not correct, can you suggest how to say 'to work in a team' in any other way?

Comment: To cooperate roughly means to work together in a team to accomplish a common goal. Therefore, cooperate in a team is redundant. Cooperate on its own is most likely enough.

Comment: Adding "together" to "work" or "work in a team" has a similar effect, as you can work in the same team but not interact much or cooperate at all.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "work" in that context.

Answer (score 1):

**cooperate or co-operate**: [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cooperate)

> 1.to work or act together or jointly for a common purpose or benefit.
>
> 2.to work or act with another or other persons willingly and agreeably.

The verb **'to cooperate'** itself is synonymous with the phrase **'to work in a team'**.  Also, (to do something) cooperatively' or 'jointly' can mean 'to work in a team'.

Answer (score 0):

Cooperated or worked on a team is fine. However, **[participated](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/participate) on a team to ____.** shows not only being on the team with a mission of ____, but has the meaning of being an active participant.

Comment: This does not fully answer the question. Why is the original, included in the OP, not correct?